# Post Title to featured Image ALT

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

i saw a interesting post on Stackoverflow where someone showed a code to to use the post title als alt tag for the featured post. So i tried to use the code for myself and change it a bit because mine differs a bit.

Original Code

```
$title=get_the_title(); the_post_thumbnail( array(150, 150),array( 'alt' =>$title) );
```

I changed it to

```
<?php $title=get_the_title(); the_post_thumbnail( array($size),array( 'alt' =>$title) ); ?>
```

The problem is that $size is not working correctly anymore it came out with 150px x 150px. (My original code is `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size ); ?>` )

I hope that someone could tell me what is wrong with it =o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$size` is already an array in your original code as it looks to be, then the argument passed will become `array(array(150,150))` instead of just `array(150,150)` and fail, so you can just do:

```
<?php $title=get_the_title(); the_post_thumbnail( $size, array( 'alt' =>$title) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working fine.. also thanks for the information with the array =), i wish you a great day (because my is now saved)